Connecting to a Kafka Docker container using Spring - Unknow Host error
I built a simple Kafka container using Docker. I now want to access it from my Spring Boot application. However, I always get a error:

java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka
2024-06-21T07:49:18.015+02:00 DEBUG
[spring-microservice-template,traceId=NONE,spanId=NONE] 23320 ---
[ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerNetworkClient : [Consumer
clientId=consumer-my-group-1, groupId=my-group] Cancelled request with
header RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=4,
clientId=consumer-my-group-1, correlationId=5, headerVersion=2) due to
node 1001 being disconnected 2024-06-21T07:49:18.015+02:00 DEBUG
[spring-microservice-template,traceId=NONE,spanId=NONE] 23320 ---
[ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer
clientId=consumer-my-group-1, groupId=my-group] FindCoordinator
request failed due to
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
2024-06-21T07:49:18.015+02:00 DEBUG
[spring-microservice-template,traceId=NONE,spanId=NONE] 23320 ---
[ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer
clientId=consumer-my-group-1, groupId=my-group] Coordinator discovery
failed, refreshing metadata

 version: '3'
 services:
zookeeper:
 image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
 container_name: zookeeper
 ports:
   - "2181:2181"
 networks:
   - kafka-net
 kafka:
image: wurstmeister/kafka
container_name: kafka
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
environment:
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "baeldung:1:1"
networks:
  - kafka-net
networks:
 kafka-net:
   driver: bridge


application.properties:
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=my-group
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key- 
deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value- 
deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.key- 
serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value- 
serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer


You need to forward and use port 9093 - OUTSIDE://localhost:9093
